# Picker view with View controller

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Lets say that I have 3 view controllers, is it possible to use picker view to select a view controller.  If so can someone point me in right direction.

```
    - (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
    {
        return 1;
    }
```

`- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return names.count;
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [names objectAtIndex:row];
}
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    switch (row) {
        case 0:

            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}`

I am trying to use picker view to select view controller that is called TfaViewController, am I on right track here and could someone help me with the code to switch between view controllers.
I apologise that my code is not set in correctly.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know how to get the user's choice from a picker view? Do you know how to go to a new controller? Break the problem down into its parts, see if you can make some progress, and come back with a more specific question if you get stuck.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @rdelmar, I have done few programs with picker view but never used picker view to choose between view controllers and I was not sure if that was possible so I dont know how to use picker view to go to a new view controller.  I have searched on this site and google but I have not found anything to get me going.

Comment: You can just use a switch statement (switch on the selected row of the picker), and push, present, or call a segue in the case statements.

Comment: I´ve edit my question @rdelmar, any chance that you could give me a help with this.

Comment: How do you want to switch between controllers? Do you want the new one to be pushed onto a navigation stack, or presented modally?  Do you know how to do either of those things? Are you using a storyboard for your controllers?

Comment: I want it to be presented modally and I am using a storyboard, when I select a row in the picker view it will take me to a view controller named TfaViewController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to instantiate the controller you want to go to and present it,

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    TfaViewcontroller *tfaVC;
    switch (row) {
        case 0: 
            tfaVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TfaViewController"];
            [self presentViewController:tfaVC animated:YES completion:nil];
            break;
        case 1:
            // do another one here

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

You need to make sure that you give the controller the same identifier in the storyboard, as you pass here in instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:.

Comment: I am getting error on this, I have the same name here and in Storyboard ID. Is there anything else I need to do.  TfaViewcontroller *tfaVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TfaViewController"];
            [self presentViewController:tfaVC animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: Unknown type name 'TfaViewController'; did you mean 'UIViewController' and Use of undeclared identifier 'tfaVC'

Comment: @Sleeperinn, did you import the TfaViewController.h file into the class where you have this code?

Comment: Yes and set the Storyboard ID on the view that I am calling

Comment: @Sleeperinn, if you've imported the correct .h file, and you've spelled the class name correctly, you shouldn't get that error. I don't know what else I can do to help.

Comment: Is it possible that i could send you the project if you could have a look at it. You have helped me before and I still have your email address.

Comment: @Sleeperinn, sure. Go ahead and send it.

Comment: @Sleeperinn, I had a syntax error in my code. You need to declare tfaVC outside of the switch statement. I've updated my answer to show the correct code.